# How to simulate significant data

Tags: r, simulation

I would like to simulate significant distributions in R: For that I would like to specify a common M and SD (Group 1 in combined with Group 2), sample size and the effect size (Cohen's d) between two groups and get data that gets significant with a t-test when the effect size is sufficient.
Can someone give me some advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll going to assume the same SD in each group and equal sample sizes (if you want to relax these assumptions you'll have to do the algebra yourself!), so pooled SD=within-group SD.  [Cohen's D](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_d) is (M2-M1)/SD, or (delta_M/SD), so delta_M = SD*Cohen_D.  M1=M-delta_M/2, M2=M+delta_M/2.

```
M <- 2         # grand mean
C <- 2         # Cohen's D
S <- 1         # pooled SD
delta_M <- S*C
m <- c(M-delta_M/2,M+delta_M/2)     # specify means for each group
n <- c(20,20)   # sample size for each group
set.seed(101)
## generate Normal deviates for each group
grp1 <- rnorm(n[1],mean=m[1],sd=S)
grp2 <- rnorm(n[2],mean=m[2],sd=S)
## run t-test
t.test(grp1,grp2)
```

---

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  grp1 and grp2
t = -7.1805, df = 37.503, p-value = 1.511e-08
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.682429 -1.502160
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.9026826 2.9949771
```

Comment: Thanks, I am missing two things: It is important for me to specify a common M + SD for both groups together, and for effect size I would prefer Cohen's d.

Comment: if both groups have the same M and SD then there is no true difference (so the test will only be significant via false positives).  If you specify an effect size that implicitly means that the two groups have different means.  I don't remember Cohen's d; can you please edit your question to include a definition?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. What I want is, if I take Group 1 + Group 2, I want to specify the common M + SD

Comment: I'm very grateful for your time and you got many upvotes, but unfortunately your solution doesn't help me, because the problem is exactly the combined M and SD and the effect size.

Comment: I did the algebra for you.  (In future note this part isn't really appropriate for a StackOverflow question -- it would be more of a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question ...)